# difference between android-maven-plugin and maven-android-plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, plugins

In the Maven Central Repository, I found the maven-android-plugin and the android-maven-plugin under the com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2 groupId. I was wondering if someone could tell me what's the difference between the two??

Answer (score 0):

They are the same plugin. At some point the plugin was renamed from "Maven Android Plugin" to "Android Maven Plugin".

Also, please note that the com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2 groupId is now also out of date. The groupId of the plugin is now com.simpligility.maven.plugins. See:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.simpligility.maven.plugins/android-maven-plugin

and also:

http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/index.html